# screen orientation issue in cocos2d v2.0 in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have old cocos2d game. I just run in xcode 8.3 on MAC OS 10.12. I am getting wrong orientation. Please find the below image.
[image]

My Code:

```
 // Create the main window
window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


// Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];



// Enable multiple touches
[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Display FSP and SPF
[director_ setDisplayStats:NO];

// set FPS at 60
[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

// attach the openglView to the director
[director_ setView:glView];

// for rotation and other messages
[director_ setDelegate:self];

// 2D projection
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

// Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
// It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
// You can change anytime.
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

// If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
// On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
// On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
// On iPhone HD: "-hd"
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

// Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

// and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
//  [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]];
//[director_ pushScene: [GamePlayLaer scene]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GamePlayLaer scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];

// Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;
//[director_ setDelegate:navController_];


[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
// make main window visible
[window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

LOG:

```
 cocos2d: OS version: 10.2 (0x0a020000)
 cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Inc.
 cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
 cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-13.0.7
 cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
 cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
 cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
 cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
 cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
 cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
 cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
 cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
 cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
 cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
 cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
 cocos2d: CCTexture2D: Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
```

Can any help me. Why this happening.
Thank you...

Comment: Have you tried changing orientation in .plist file?

Comment: Yes, I tried .plist orientation but no use.

Comment: You can set the iOS application's orientation (in general, not only cocos2d) in primary project's setting in XCode. Didn't it work?